# Azure Api Builder with docker .env

Tags: azure, docker, environment-variables, builder

I'm currently trying to use a .env file together with the dab-config.json in a docker container.

Since Azure recently published the option to use environments. I changed the dab-config.json by using the `@env()` syntax for the credentials. The credentials are stored in a seperate .env file.

My problem is, that when I run following command it is loading only the dab-config.json. I don't know how to reference the .env file with docker. The command looks as follows.

```
sudo docker run -it -v ".:/App/samples" -p PORT:PORT mcr.microsoft.com/azure-databases/data-api-builder --ConfigFileName ./samples/dab-config.json
```

I tried to use `--env-file` with the path to the env file.
I tried to add another command `--ConfigFileName` with path to the env file

Comment: Can you also share what error are you facing, or how do you know that env file is not being loaded?

Comment: sure, when I'm running the command:

` sudo docker run -it -v ".:/App/samples" -p 5000:5000 mcr.microsoft.com/azure-databases/data-api-builder --ConfigFileName ./samples/dab-config.json`

following output is shown. Both the dab-conifg and .env are in the same folder.

`Starting the runtime engine...
Loading config file from ./samples/dab-config.json.
Unable to launch the runtime due to an error.`

Comment: dab-config looks like this :

`"data-source": {
    "database-type": "mssql",
    "connection-string": "@env('dev-db-connection')"
  }`

env looks like this:

`dev-db-connection="Server=tcp:bla-sql-server.database.windows.net,0000;Initial Catalog=db1;Connection Timeout=30;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=bla;Password=123456;"`

Answer (score 0):

The way I understand is that you reference `.env` file inside `dab-config.json` as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-api-builder/configuration-file#setting-environment-variables) using `@env()` syntax.

> Create an .env file listing the environment variable key-value pairs
> one line each and place this file in the same directory as the
> configuration file.

Sample .env file:

```
my-connection-string="Server=tcp:127.0.0.1,1433;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=USER_NAME;Password=PASSWORD;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Connection Timeout=5;"
DAB_ENVIRONMENT=Development
```

Sample dab-config.json:

```json
{
  "connection-string": "@env('my-connection-string')"
}
```

So you can simply keep it in the same folder where your configuration file is present and it should be able to reference it. I don't think the reference need to be given directly via docker.

Comment: No it does not work like this. I tried that. You need to load the .env file somehow, otherwise how should the config file know where to take the information from.

Comment: @Chronos The reason I think this should work is because we are mounting the folder using `-v` flag and referencing the config file inside that folder and which should also make the environment file automatically available after mounting the whole folder. But I will still attempt to check again